# How to display sign-changes in Temperature series in a histogram?

Tags: python, histogram

I have a temperature dataset with 40 years of hourly temperature data. I would like to plot when sign changes take place in a histogram with on the x-axis the different months and on the y axis the number of times a sign-change occurred during this month in any of the 40 years.

So far I only managed to count the amount of sign changes using the following code:

```
positive= Ta>0
count = np.logical_xor(positive[1:],positive[:-1]).sum()
count += not(positive[0])
print (count)
```

Can anybody help me with how I can achieve this histogram? I think once I have the dates at which a sign change takes place in for example a dataframe, I can probably create the histogram with something like:

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

Ta is a series, with it's date/time as index:

```
inputfiles = os.listdir('./Input')
for file in inputfiles:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        climatefile = './Input/%s'%file

file1 = pd.read_csv(climatefile, sep=',')
file1.D = pd.to_datetime(file1.time_npt, dayfirst=True)
file1.index = file1.D

Ta = file1.tdsvll
```

So the name of the temperature series is tdsvll:

```
 time_npt            tdsvll     
2010-01-01 00:00:00 -10.2134     
2010-01-01 01:00:00 -10.5974
....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the column names of your df?

Comment: Ta is a series, with it's date/time as index:

`inputfiles = os.listdir('./Input')
 for file in inputfiles:
     if file.endswith('.csv'):
         climatefile = './Input/%s'%file

 file1 = pd.read_csv(climatefile, sep=',')
 file1.D = pd.to_datetime(file1.time_npt, dayfirst=True)
 file1.index = file1.D

 Ta = file1.tdsvll`

So the name of the temperature series is tdsvll

    `time_npt                          tdsvll
    2010-01-01 00:00:00 -10.2134
    2010-01-01 01:00:00 -10.5974`